# How to use Visual Studio Dialog Editor with just C++ Win32 API (no MFC or WinForms)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, winapi, user-interface, dialog

I'm quite new to GUI programming in C++ and I'm trying to use the Visual Studio Dialog Editor.

I've already created a dialog and assigned it a Dialog Procedure but I don't know to get the hwnd handles for any controls I add from the Toolbox.

How do I interact with the Dialog Editor controls without using MFC or WinForms?

In this specific instance, I want to create and populate a Listbox and buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dialog template has controls defined with dialog identifiers. When the real dialog is instantiated from template, you can use [`GetDlgItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77d16yhw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) API to get a `HWND` for your control, given its identifier.

See use of `GetDlgItem` under item 4 here: [The Modal Dialog and Windows Common Controls 3](http://www.tenouk.com/visualcplusmfc/visualcplusmfc5b.html) when the code gets a scrollbar handle.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out a fraction of a second before you answered!